# Coldfusion SQL injection? failing a web application inspection

Tags: coldfusion, sql-injection

Ok,  I'm stumped, I have a CF11 web application that is failing a web application audit report for SQL injection, this report is made by Acunetix.

Anyways, the report gives me 10 pages on my site that is vulnerable to sql injection, but i checked the code , and I am in fact using cfqueryparam in each of these instances

example of one of the queries called by the handler

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.DSN#" name="qResult" result="r">
        update  #table# s
        set s.loader_status = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ucase(arguments.status)#">
        <cfif isDefined("bio_loader_status") and bio_loader_status neq ''>
         , s.bio_loader_status = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ucase(bio_loader_status)#">
         </cfif>
         , s.session_id = NULL
         , s.session_expiration = NULL
         <cfif isDefined("arguments.rowid") and arguments.rowid neq ''>
                where s.rowid = CHARTOROWID(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.rowid#">)
         </cfif>

    </cfquery>
```

everything I have read tells me that I am protected against sql attacks (using cfquery param, using datasurce and table variables, etc), yet the report claims otherwise

```
URL encoded GET input rowid was set to 1'"
Error message found: Error Executing Database Query
GET /index.cfm/status?rowid=1'%22&type=billing HTTP/1.1
```

can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong? or is the report not correct in its assumptions?

Comment: So, the report is claiming that your code is throwing an error in a situation where it should be?

Comment: @KevinB haha i dont know! I think so, I mean I'm not sure why its claiming this is a successful sql injection, it doesnt appear to be

Comment: What condition is it looking for to determine that it was successful? 200 status code response?

Comment: @KevinB i am unsure, it stands to reason that is the case

Comment: Where does #table# come from?

Comment: If `rowid=1'"` is making it through to your query, I don't think `cfqueryparam` likes double quote characters. That definitely won't be a valid query string.

Comment: They want you to graciously handle the fact that `rowid` is not a number, they don't want to see the standard error message `Error Executing Database Query` they want something like `Hey, there is not such row id, all the Jedi have left.`

Comment: What web server are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Furthering Alex's assertion:

> They want you to graciously handle the fact that rowid is not a number, they don't want to see the standard error message

My previous employer has regular penetration tests (pen tests) performed against their applications. The error messages output from CF will just render the strings of the attack on the screen. This is fine for non-production, non-QA environments where you need or want debugging information to display on screen. In production, you never want to tip your hand as to where the code tripped up.

The error message `GET /index.cfm/status?rowid=1'%22&type=billing HTTP/1.1` tells the attacker which file and its path, along with a URL parameter that it can further attack. If this file was an include in your request stack and that file can be requested directly, you may then be open to further attacks. You need to catch this error and output a  message.

If you have to be logged in to access this URL, that's one thing. A public URL shouldn't have any information specific to the problem. Don't output something like, `The rowID must be an Integer` or `rowID is invalid`. That will just cause more attacks. `Invalid request` is fine for a public URL error.

Now, to the case when `<cfqueryparam>` actually can't stop an injection attack. Some legacy stored procedures at my previous company use dynamic SQL. Much like in CF, strings would be concatenated inside the proc and the the SQL execute command would run the final SQL string. It is possible to pass an encoded string to `<cfqueryparam>` that will then get injected into the SQL string inside the proc as it is pieced together. For this, we had to update piles of old procs to validate string parameters, looking for certain strings to reject.

If possible, you should add a [Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall) to your infrastructure. The [Online ColdFusion Meetup Group](https://www.meetup.com/coldfusionmeetup/events/245685781/) is having a presentation on one software based WAF for CF applications tomorrow. I'm sure it will be recorded if you can't attend. I just last night finished moving my current CF site to AWS, where we made sure to add their [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) to our stack for security. This doesn't mean that we don't need to properly catch errors and show appropriate messages, but it does tend to lighten the load when you can have it reject known attack vectors before the request even gets to the application server.

Comment: "In production, you never want to tip your hand as to where the code tripped up." <<< Can't be stressed enough.

Comment: Ok awesome, sorry for the verbose question but this helped tremedously

by the way it is not a public url, it is behind a firewall , requires a vpn login, and two step authentication in the browser, my feeling is this is overkill but thats probably what all front end devs say